# How can I fix that the moving background image doesn't glitch?

Tags: html, css

Here is my project I'm working on: http://i385549.hera.fhict.nl/auto.html.

So after every 5 seconds, the road just pops back to its starting point. But that results in an ugly "glitch". It would like that it just goes smooth the whole time. How do I fix this?

```
#banner{
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
margin-top: 34%;
background: url(../img2/road.jpg) repeat-x;
animation: animate-background linear 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes animate-background {
from { background-position: 0%; }
to { background-position: 100%; }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change your animation

```
#banner{
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
margin-top: 34%;
background: url(../img2/road.jpg) repeat-x;
animation: animate-background linear 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes animate-background {
0% { background-position: 0%; }
50% { background-position: 100%; }
100% { background-position: 0%; }
}
```

Comment: set the percents like you want. for example you can change the 50% state to 80% state, to have the rollback faster

Comment: Thanks, but I would like that the road just keeps on going the same way without the little glitch. I have tried a lot of changing with the percents but nothing has made that glitch go way yet

Comment: EDIT: the rollback is now unnoticable. I have just tried alot of different percents and if I start with 20% and end with 111% it was fixed. So thanks!

Comment: It's not a glitch, it's just jumping from the last animation frame to the first but the position of the image in this moment is not the same which creates the jump.